# Cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type '[String : AnyObject]?'

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, serialization

I am trying to fetch the json from url. While Serialization json it is giving error?

```
 static func fetchFeatureApp(){
            let urlString="http://ebmacs.net/ubereats/Api/all_product?id=1"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)!

         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url)){ (data, responce, error) in
            if error != nil
                {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                do{
                   let json=try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)) //as! [String:AnyObject]?//as! [AnyObject]?//as! String? //as! [String:AnyObject]//as! [String: Any]
 //////////Error here

                    //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any] //program is crashing 
                    var appCategories=[AppCategory]()
                    for dict in json["products"] as! [[String :AnyObject]]{///////Error Here
                        let appCategory = AppCategory()
                        appCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                        appCategories.append(appCategory)
                    }
                    print(appCategories)
                }catch let err{
                    print(error)
                }
            }.resume()

        }
```

The class for Json is

```
class App:NSObject  {
    var product_id:NSNumber?
    var product_name:String?
    var product_description:String?
    var image_url:String?
    var product_price:NSNumber?
    var name:String?
}
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD04Q.jpg)

At following lines I am getting error:

Error 1:

```
 `let json=try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)) //as! [String:AnyObject]?//as! [AnyObject]?//as! String? //as! [String:AnyObject]//as! [String: Any]`
```

> Cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type '[String :
>   AnyObject]?'

Error 2:

```
for dict in json["products"] as! [[String :AnyObject]]{ /////////////error
```

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

How to remove these error ?

Comment: Please check root object of the JSON you expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to parse JSON is to unwrap the optional safely with optional bindings.

Please read the JSON. It's very easy. `{}` represents a dictionary (`[String:Any]` in Swift), `[]` an array (`[[String:Any]]`) and `.mutableContainers` is nonsense in Swift anyway.

The root object is a dictionary, the value for key `products` is an array

```
struct AppCategory {
    let id, name, description, url, price : String
}

do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!) as? [String:Any] {
        if let products = jsonResult["products"] as? [[String:String]] {
            var appCategories = [AppCategory]()
            for product in products {
                let category = AppCategory(id: product["product_id"] ?? "",
                                           name: product["product_name"] ?? "",
                                           description: product["product_description"] ?? "",
                                           url: product["image_url"] ?? "",
                                           price: product["product_price"] ?? "")
                appCategories.append(category)
            }
            print(appCategories)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: let category = AppCategory(id: product["product_id"] ?? "",
                  This line gives Error :Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Comment: I don't know the structure of your `AppCategory` object, so I added a simple `struct` to provide a working solution.

Comment: i have updated Question and included class for json .class App:NSObject  {
    var product_id:NSNumber?
    var product_name:String?
    var product_description:String?
    var image_url:String?
    var product_price:NSNumber?
    var name:String?
}

Comment: 1) The class name doesn't match the class in the code 2) You don't need a `class` 3) You don't need `NSNumber` 4) You don't need optionals 5) Variable names are supposed to be *camelCased* in Swift. - Please try my suggested `struct`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any]
```

Edit: This would only work if the top level object in your json is actually a dictionary and not an array. Would be helpful if you could post a redacted version of your json response.

**This code is working for me with your url.**